# When an mht file is opened in IE11 , mode is getting changed IE7(default)

Tags: internet-explorer-11, mhtml

Any .mht file opened using IE11, the mode is getting changed to default IE 7(this has been observed using F12-> Developer Tools).

This problem exists with only IE11, I have tried in IE9  and  .mht files are working fine.
1. Is this a known issue?
2. why the mode set to IE7(default), when IE11 is used?
Would you please provide any workaround to make sure that its always set IE mode to latest(edge).
Regards,
Syam Devendla